# Debian apt-get fails to fetch packages with high latency low bandwith connection

Tags: networking, debian, apt-get

I have issues on a machine with high latency and low bandwidth connection. apt-get fails to fetch packages. It says:

```
Fehl:45 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64 amd64 6.1.52-1
Verbindung fehlgeschlagen [IP: 199.232.42.132 80]
E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/l/linux/linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64_6.1.52-1_amd64.deb Verbindung fehlgeschlagen [IP: 199.232.42.132 08]
```

I have a network connection with high latency and low bandwith over a rather restrictive company firewall. To exacerbate the problem, the machine I want to run is in a virtualbox.
The debian installed is bookworm.
However I ran some tests. Browsing internet is working. And I can fetch the packages by simply running

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/l/linux/linux-headers-6.1.0-12-amd64_6.1.52-1_amd64.deb
```

on the very same machine with no issues. So the firewall isn't blocking the access to the security archive completely. It seems apt-get has some different means of fetching the files than wget. Maybe different handshake or timeouts? Are there options I can change to make it behave more like wget?

Comment: Instead of apt-get try apt.

Comment: @harrymc works better, but why? Is apt-get unmaintained crap meanwhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the poster, using `apt` got better results than `apt-get`.

Both commands work differently and on different levels, where `apt`
was more intended for end-users and does more actions automatically.
The fact that it worked better for the user doesn't mean that
`apt-get` should be discarded or that it will always work worse
than `apt`.

For more information see
[Difference Between apt and apt-get Explained](https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/).